# How can I check in a MOSS Designer workflow if a user is a member of a given group?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm building a basic workflow through MOSS designer, as part of one of the conditions, I'm trying to determine whether or not I can determine whether or not the the user that created the workflow instance is a member of a particular group, if so act in one method otherwise just don't.  None of the built-in actions seem to be able to accomodate this (they want specific users, not groups), any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the actions in SharePoint Designer Workflows are extremely limited.  We've had to install an open-source add-on component to get basic functionality like this: http://www.codeplex.com/SPDActivities

It worked well for us without any problems.  However, you'll need to have permission to log intot he Central Administration server and add/deploy/activate the addin.